# My AngularJS scope is not updating in the model

Tags: angularjs

ave created a application to display all the users in my mysql database, everything works fine but when my php code returns the json containing the data the scope is update but am not getting any display

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html> 
     <head>
      <title>Simple Dynamic Score Board | By Kascique Lowmans</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
      <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <script>

          var webapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    webapp.controller('myusers', function($scope, $http){
          $scope.users = [];
    $http.get("selectdata.php").then(function(response){
         $scope.users = response.data;
                                     $scope.$apply();
                                     alert($scope.users);
                                     
     });
                               // $scope.$watch("users", function(){ alert('users scope changed');});
    
    });
    
    
    
      </script>
  <body data-ng-app="myapp" >
   <div class="control-group">
   <h1>Select a user</h1>
     <div data-ng-controller="myusers" >
    <label class="control control--radio" data-ng-repeat="x in users"><span>{{$index + 1}}</span> {{ x.firstname +' '+x.lastname }} <b>{{ x.score}}</b>
     <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
     <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label><br/>
                                <h1 id="trail"></h1>
    <button ng-click="click()">+ Add score</button>
     </div>
   <footer>
                &copy; copyright <a href="http://www.kasciquelowmans.ml/">Kascique Lowmans</a>
            </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a reason to use a very very outdated version of Angular?

Comment: nope i just tried that one should work still

Answer (score 1):

You have not assigned anything to ng-model. Correct me if i am wrong but i dont see any ng-model in your entire code.

Comment: Why does he need ng-model to display users data?

Comment: The question is not clear but i believe he is trying to add user to some array since there is ng-click function assigned to the button.

Comment: sorry my mistake i mean in my expressions

Comment: I made some mistakes in the question. Please read the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You made two errors in your code

1) incorrect html. Head tag includes body tag. 
2) you should not call $scope.apply from $http promise callback, since it will be called by Angular.

Below is a slightly changed snipped and it works.

```js
var webapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    webapp.controller('myusers', function($scope, $http){
     $scope.users = [];
    $http.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10").then(function(response){
                     $scope.users = response.data.results;
                                     
     });
     $scope.regUser = function(index){ 
          $scope.thereguser = index;
     } 

    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group" data-ng-app="myapp">
   <h1>Select a user</h1>
     <div data-ng-controller="myusers" >
    <label class="control control--radio" data-ng-repeat="x in users"><span>{{$index + 1}}</span> {{ x.name.first }} <b>{{ x.score}}</b>
     <input type="radio" name="radio"/>
     <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label><br/>
                                <h1 id="trail"></h1>
    <button ng-click="click()">+ Add score</button>
     </div>
   <footer>
                &copy; copyright <a href="http://www.kasciquelowmans.ml/">Kascique Lowmans</a>
            </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry i noticed that i have made that html error but lets just ignore it. The ng-click that you see there is for another feature that's working fine so just ignore it

Comment: maybe its my php code but i don't see anything wrong with it

Comment: Ok, try to change your code to do it same as my example. It should works for you. Than replace step by step url and bindings to find where is error.

Answer (score 0):

How do you change your scope? Via the click() function? Can you post it?
BTW you don't need `$scope.$apply()` inside of an angular operation ($http.get in this case) as it automatically does it.